# Is llvm's dyn_cast still used as an alternative to dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, c++17, llvm, dynamic-cast

I'm trying to optimize some code like this:

```
// RequestType inherits MessageType 
void receive_message (MessageType* M) 
{
   auto msg = dynamic_cast<RequestType>(M);
   if (msg != nullptr) 
   {
       // do something
   }
}
```

The program doesn't know until runtime what specific type `MessageType` will be.

In the code, `dynamic_cast` is used repeatedly, and is taking up lots of resources. So I searched for alternatives, and LLVM's `dyn_cast` came up. From the manual it seems that `dyn_cast` doesn't use VMT, so is more efficient that way.

However, when I searched for its use, there does not seem to be much on this topic? Most of the questions date to the 2010s, so I'm wondering if it's still used nowadays, or if there's a better alternative (e.g. `typeid`, etc) / or if there's a reason it's not widely used?

It'd be great if someone could shed light on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you look at the LLVM source code ([here's a list of recent commits](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commits/main)), you'll see dyn_cast<> used. Used in the LLVM source code, whose classes have the necessary plumbing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While LLVM's `dyn_cast` templates are "an alternative dynamic_cast", it also requires the user to implement LLVM's RTTI which is described in detail in this document: https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates

To answer your question; yes, dyn_cast and friends are still used by LLVM today. LLVM rolls its own form of RTTI because it's way faster and cheaper than what the standard provides so you got that part right.

If you decide to go down this route, you can refer to the LLVM documentation on how to implement LLVM-style RTTI: https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html